# Multiple htaccess files with different rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have 2 .htaccess files - one in root directory, another in subdirectory:

accordingly docroot/ and /subdirectory/docroot (this one works like a separate account).

The problem is that there are different rewrite rules in both files. Basicly, the problem is that the .htaccess in subdirectory doesn't work and/or is ignored.

What I am trying to achieve is to have one set of rewrite rules for docroot and other set of rewrite rules for subdirectory/docroot

edit:
the .htaccess file in subdirectory/docroot basicly strips index.php from url, and it actually works, but when i go to subdirectory/user it redirects to subdirectory/user/login (instead of subdirectory/index.php/user/login -- this parts is ok) but the website shows the root page (not subdirectory, but domain root)

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide what you have in the respective .htaccess files?

Comment: I found what the problem was. The htaccess file in subdirectory had wrong rewrite base set. Now everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to set RewriteBase to that particular subdirectory to make things work.